# Talend Online Data Preparation: Invalid version format from engine-info service, expecting yyyy-MM format, value provided was unknown

Tags: excel, talend

I'm working on the
Talend online version, using the product Data Preparation.

I setted a local connection,
I uploaded an **Excel file** (.xlsx) that is corrected detected,

but when I click "**View Sample**" or "**Validate**"
it shows an error pop-up message:

```
Invalid version format from engine-info service, expecting yyyy-MM format, value provided was unknown
```

[image]

Another screenshot of the error:

[image]

```
Cannot fetch sample for dataset id 67f577be-b0de-42a5-a10d-cb73ebe4ef69 with cause : WRONG_ENGINE_VERSION_FORMAT
Verify the dataset configuration or connection properties
```

***What is the "version" referred in the error messages ?***